# Encrypting images when uploading to Amazon S3 bucket IN TRANSIT

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-amplify

**SOFTWARE/ CODE**:

I am using `react native` with `Amplify` library to upload images from my mobile app to Amazon AWS S3 bucket. I am using the following line code:

```
Storage.put(newFile.name, newFile, {
      level: 'private'});
```

I am able to successfully upload the file.

**MORE BACKGROUND:**

I have enabled default encryption for S3 objects in my bucket. That is whenever an object reaches the bucket - it is encrypted using default encryption before being saved to disk of S3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-encryption.html

The upload operation (during Storage.put() call) happens in 2 steps:

**Step 1:** The file that I send from my react native mobile app, goes **unencrypted** to Amazon S3 bucket.

**Step 2:** This unencrypted file when it reaches the S3 bucket - it is then encrypted and saved to disk in S3.

**MY PROBLEM:**

I want to enable encryption **in transit**. That is I want encryption at step 1 itself.

Basically I don't want server side encryption. I want client side encryption.

**WHAT I HAVE RESEARCHED:**

Even the amplify doc shows the example explained in step 1 and step 2. This is not what I want.
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/#encrypted-uploads

The example given in the above amplify doc will do the same thing - that the file will be sent unencrypted to S3 and then when it reaches the bucket - it will be encrypted and saved. This is not what I want.

Comment: Let me know if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: I think it is generally encrypted when it is being sent, because Storage.put uses a https post request (with graphql) to upload the file.

Comment: Agreed with @Engam above.  What makes you think it is not encrypted when being sent?

Comment: If you ask `encrypt in transit`, usually the asnwer is - use https. If using https, the traffic is encrypted.